# Pre-compiled FirebaseFirestore in pod throws Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: flutter, firebase

When I add FirebaseFirestore pre-compiled version in PodFile to reduce build times, this build process fails. This is the relevant info:

Error:

```
Error (Xcode): Undefined symbols:

Error (Xcode): Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 13 Pro.
```

Flutter doctor:

> [✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.16.0, on macOS 14.1.1 23B81
> darwin-arm64, locale en-ES)  [✓] Android toolchain - develop for
> Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)  [✓] Xcode - develop for
> iOS and macOS (Xcode 15.0.1)  [✗] Chrome - develop for the web (Cannot
> find Chrome executable at /Applications/Google
> Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome) ! Cannot find Chrome. Try
> setting CHROME_EXECUTABLE to a Chrome executable.  [✓] Android Studio
> (version 2022.3)  [✓] VS Code (version 1.84.2)  [✓] Connected device
> (2 available)  [✓] Network resources

PodFile:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '12.1'

# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def flutter_root
  generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
  unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
  end

  File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
    matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
    return matches[1].strip if matches
  end
  raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
end

require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)

flutter_ios_podfile_setup

target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!


  ***** HERE IS THE PROBLEM *****
  pod 'FirebaseFirestore', :git => 'https://github.com/invertase/firestore-ios-sdk-frameworks.git', :tag => '10.18.0'
  *******************************


  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
  target 'RunnerTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
  end
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)


    ***** ADDED THIS LINES ****
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '12.1'
    end
    ***************************


  end
end
```